# Multiple conditional loops in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list containing several dfs in every element. Those dfs have different names, so I´m trying to rename some variables so all list elements would have the same header. But for some reason my looping is only returning some elements, and not all of them. I believe there is something to do with the "else" parameter. The problem begins when the element doesn't have the name that i´m looking for, and therefore the statement is false. What am I doing wrong?

```
lista_result <- list()
 for (i in seq_along(lista_lotes)){
   print(i)
  x <- lista_lotes[[i]]
  y <- names(x)
  if (sum(grepl("nome_completo", y)) == 1){
x <- x %>%
  rename(figure_name = nome_completo) } else { return(x)}
  if (sum(grepl("title", y)) == 1) {
x <- x %>%
  rename(office_title = title) } else {return(x)}
  if (sum(grepl("numero", y)) == 1) {
x <- x %>%
  rename(figure_id = numero) } else { return(x)}
  if (sum(grepl("url1", y)) == 1) {
x <- x %>%
  rename(url = url1)} else {return(x)}
  if (sum(grepl("State", y)) == 1){
x <- x %>%
  rename(district_id = State) } else { return(x)}
  x <- x %>%
select(figure_name, office_title, figure_id, district_id, url, nome_arq)
lista_result[[i]] <- x
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `lista_lotes`

Comment: This looks like a good use case for `case_when()` from `dplyr`, where you just list out the which names should be translated how.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve talked to my friend and we developed a code that worked. It seems that plyr rename  function allows me to not use the conditionals (which does not happen with the dplyr::rename function) :

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
lista_result <- list()
for (i in seq_along(lista_lotes)){
 print(i) 
  x <- lista_lotes[[i]]
  x <- plyr::rename(x, replace = c("nome_completo" = "figure_name",
                               "title" = "office_title",
                               "numero" = "figure_id",
                               "url1" = "url",
                               "State" = "district_id",
                               "Federal District"  = "district_id"), TRUE)
 x <- x %>%
mutate_all(as.character) %>%
 select(figure_name, office_title,district_id, figure_id, url, nome_arq )
lista_result[[i]] <- x
}
```